# How can I add the server name to the subject line of a SSIS subscription email?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting, ssis

How can I add the server name to the subject line of a SSIS subscription email?

In Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) RDL report files uploaded are often set with the ability to send out periodic email alerts. On the SSIS 2008 system, this is called "Subscriptions". When a new email alert is set up, there are system defined strings in the Subject line which is presented as default as:
@ReportName was executed at @ExecutionTime

How can I add a new item to this subject line for the server name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ReportName  and @ExecutionTime are the only available Parameter, see Create and Manage Subscriptions for Native Mode Report Servers => 7. "You can edit the subject but note that the @ReportName and @ExecutionTime are the only global variables supported in the Subject field"

Answer (score 0):

These variables are probably from the [Global Collections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms157274(v=sql.90)#globals) in Reporting Services Expressions. This seems the closest variable to what you are looking for:

> `ReportServerUrl` *String*
>
> The URL of the report server on which the report is being run.

Keep in mind that that mainstream [support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/end-of-mainstream-support-for-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2008-r2/) for SQL Server 2008 has ended 7/8/2014 and the extended support is ending 7/9/2019. It's a good time to upgrade.